# Django Views Query

Tags: django-views

I have a view in which I get data from a form and use it to run a python script within the view. The python script gives some output and needs to prompt to user to proceed further and perform other functionality.

How can i do all this in a single view ??

my views.py

```
class DeployWizard(SessionWizardView):

    template = "deploy_form.html"
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs) :
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        #process all the data form the form

        #call the script with some of the the form data as argument 

        # display the output to the user and ask the user to proceed (something like "Yes", "No") and proceed further

        # again call the python script with some other arguments

        return rendor_to_response("done.html", {'form_data' : form_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use either Django's [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) or [form preview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/) depending on your precise use case.

The former will help you if you need a classic multi-step wizard, the latter if you just need the user to confirm his input.

Comment: I am already using the form wizard. I don't want to confirm the user input in the form rather I want the user to confirm the output of the python script which I am calling inside the view and proceed further to continue calling the script again.

Comment: I have been stuck in this situation for a while now. An answer would be really helpful to me.

Comment: Since you can't output anything in the middle of the view and then continue executing it, you will need to call the script twice: the first time to show the output to the user and receive confirmation, the second time to proceed further.

Obviously this is not what you need. What you should do is to split this view in two parts: do the first part of your script in one view, save its results somewhere, receive confirmation and then continue processing the saved results in the second view.

Comment: I just need to do what you just mentioned in your comment.
"you will need to call the script twice: the first time to show the output to the user and receive confirmation, the second time to proceed further."

Comment: if I use two views then how will I use the form data in other view